# how to sort 14 columns not by row based on their value not using if condition in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, sorting

I am working on a data frame of prediction from testing images. I have a list of which containing 14 values and each value is class. I want to compare the performance of a model prediction on different probabilities.
Now I want these values to place in a new data frame with a name.
After that, I want to make them sorted based on descending order like 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1, etc
how to sort those columns and in place change?
Example data:

```
col_name = ['Atelectasis', 'Cardiomegaly', 'Consolidation', 'Edema', 'Effusion', 'Emphysema', 'Fibrosis', 'Hernia',
        'Infiltration', 'Mass', 'Nodule', 'Pleural_Thickening', 'Pneumonia', 'Pneumothorax']
[0.2268, 0.0717, 0.2414, 0.0845, 0.2153, 0.2802, 0.3154, 0.2922, 0.1558,
         0.3638, 0.2032, 0.1259, 0.2359, 0.4329]
```

I don't want row-wise sorting not adding new col to the data frame I just sort based on columns values which are greater will be on the left side as above I shows an example.
Thanks

Comment: `df.sort_values(by=0, axis=1)`

Comment: I understand the idea but what if I have 25k images and each image having a prediction like this and I am doing adding the prediction to my data frame and again checking for sorting by descending form. Is it possible? Is it possible to sort every time as in this single list the last value is larger but what if 2nd prediction came and I get 4th value greater and I want a larger value in the front column? Does it effect the previous prediction sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following Dataframe :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> l_data_raw = [[0.2268, 0.0717, 0.2414, 0.0845, 0.2153, 0.2802, 0.3154, 0.2922, 0.1558, 0.3638, 0.2032, 0.1259, 0.2359, 0.4329],
...               [0.0468, 0.7172, 0.4143, 0.8452, 0.1534, 0.8025, 0.1546, 0.9227, 0.5583, 0.3387, 0.2325, 0.3259, 0.3597, 0.3259],
...               [0.2683, 0.0173, 0.4154, 0.8475, 0.7153, 0.2027, 0.3543, 0.2752, 0.7558, 0.3853, 0.3752, 0.7359, 0.8559, 0.2958],
...               [0.5788, 0.5617, 0.2754, 0.7645, 0.7853, 0.4602, 0.8754, 0.2332, 0.8768, 0.3768, 0.2782, 0.7659, 0.7859, 0.3729]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=l_data_raw, index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=['Atelectasis', 'Cardiomegaly', 'Consolidation', 'Edema', 'Effusion', 'Emphysema', 'Fibrosis', 'Hernia', 'Infiltration', 'Mass', 'Nodule', 'Pleural_Thickening', 'Pneumonia', 'Pneumothorax'])
>>> df
    Atelectasis Cardiomegaly    Consolidation   Edema   Effusion    Emphysema   Fibrosis    Hernia  Infiltration    Mass    Nodule  Pleural_Thickening  Pneumonia   Pneumothorax
0   0.2268      0.0717          0.2414          0.0845  0.2153      0.2802      0.3154      0.2922  0.1558          0.3638  0.2032  0.1259              0.2359      0.4329
1   0.0468      0.7172          0.4143          0.8452  0.1534      0.8025      0.1546      0.9227  0.5583          0.3387  0.2325  0.3259              0.3597      0.3259
2   0.2683      0.0173          0.4154          0.8475  0.7153      0.2027      0.3543      0.2752  0.7558          0.3853  0.3752  0.7359              0.8559      0.2958
3   0.5788      0.5617          0.2754          0.7645  0.7853      0.4602      0.8754      0.2332  0.8768          0.3768  0.2782  0.7659              0.7859      0.3729
```

We can `stack` the `DataFrame` and then reorder each image group by values like so :

```py
>>> df_stacked = df.stack().to_frame().reset_index(drop=False)
>>> df_stacked.columns = ['image', 'class', 'value']
>>> df_agg = df_stacked.groupby(['image', 'class']).agg({'value':sum})
>>> df_agg['value'].groupby('image', group_keys=False).nlargest(14).to_frame()
        value
image   class
0       Pneumothorax        0.4329
        Mass                0.3638
        Fibrosis            0.3154
        Hernia              0.2922
        Emphysema           0.2802
        Consolidation       0.2414
        Pneumonia           0.2359
        Atelectasis         0.2268
        Effusion            0.2153
        Nodule              0.2032
        Infiltration        0.1558
        Pleural_Thickening  0.1259
        Edema               0.0845
        Cardiomegaly        0.0717
1       Hernia              0.9227
        Edema               0.8452
        Emphysema           0.8025
        Cardiomegaly        0.7172
        Infiltration        0.5583
        Consolidation       0.4143
        Pneumonia           0.3597
        Mass                0.3387
        Pleural_Thickening  0.3259
        Pneumothorax        0.3259
        Nodule              0.2325
        Fibrosis            0.1546
        Effusion            0.1534
        Atelectasis         0.0468
2       Pneumonia           0.8559
        Edema               0.8475
        Infiltration        0.7558
        Pleural_Thickening  0.7359
        Effusion            0.7153
        Consolidation       0.4154
        Mass                0.3853
        Nodule              0.3752
        Fibrosis            0.3543
        Pneumothorax        0.2958
        Hernia              0.2752
        Atelectasis         0.2683
        Emphysema           0.2027
        Cardiomegaly        0.0173
3       Infiltration        0.8768
        Fibrosis            0.8754
        Pneumonia           0.7859
        Effusion            0.7853
        Pleural_Thickening  0.7659
        Edema               0.7645
        Atelectasis         0.5788
        Cardiomegaly        0.5617
        Emphysema           0.4602
        Mass                0.3768
        Pneumothorax        0.3729
        Nodule              0.2782
        Consolidation       0.2754
        Hernia              0.2332
```

Comment: Thanks, man I understand the idea but what if I have 25k images and each image having a prediction like this and I am doing adding the prediction to my data frame and again checking for sorting by descending form.
Is it possible?
Is it possible to sort every time as in this single list the last value is larger but what if 2nd prediction came and I get 4th value greater and I want a larger value in the front column?
Does it effect the previous prediction sorting?

Comment: I updated the answer to take in consideration several images. Hope it helps !

Comment: hurra, that great I was looking for that but I am not an expert in pandas that is why I couldn't.
Now I have only one question I am able to make the single dict for class and its prediction.
But if I am doing like yours then how I make that dict you prepared to make the key in list form.
Thanks buddy for your kind help

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to declare the `DataFrame` using lists in the way you did in your question. Don't hesitate to upvote the answer if it helps you, always happy to help.

Comment: well as you can see my repo that I started the journey of asking and answering questions recently and I am diving into the developing world. So I upvote and make it an answer but it can't upvote due to low repo I need 3 more. Sorry for that

Comment: Don't worry, the most important part is that this answer helps you.

Comment: please upvote my question someone devotes and now its negative and its cut my two repo which I need to complete to upvote of any and.

Comment: Hello tlemtali, I need help regiarding the same dataframe. Now I want the True Positive Rate that how much correct in the predicted probabilities and compares to ground truth. I have prepared like this  now in this data frame I want that if the ground truth means the original label which are in a coulms having greater probably for single or for multi  labels.
In short find like this

Comment: In this case don't hesitate to open a new question an put its link here in comment so I can have a look.

Comment: here is the link brother:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68590183/how-to-find-tpr-and-tpr-from-its-labels-and-probablites-to-evaluate-my-model