# how to find TPR and TPR from its labels and probablites to evaluate my model?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, model

I need help regarding the data frame which I have asked in this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394653/how-to-sort-14-columns-not-by-row-based-on-their-value-not-using-if-condition-in/68395682#68395682). Now I want to evaluate the model to find the total; like finding `True Positive Rate` and `False Negative Rate`. that how much correct in the predicted probabilities and compares to ground truth. I have prepared a data frame like below now in this data frame I want that if the ground truth means the original label which is in a column having greater probably for single or for multi labels. In short find like this

I sharing the link where the file is uploaded:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AoDI7kJyFDyAD2Gurz8SOQUGOVckwE57/view?usp=sharing

if not understand then I am explaining below:

```
img_name       label                     14 disease col- containing probab- of each class

0001        [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Emphysema','Hernia']]  0.4,0.6,0.9,0.8, 0.8
```

Details are in that link of example `csv`.

I want to get the True positive if the label col- having the highest probability from the rest of 14 columns will be a `True Positive Value`. How to get this I can't understand as I am validating the model on another dataset/test data.
some images having multilabel so I want that too e.g uploaded file having this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your new `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df
                file    set     label                                        bbx    Atelectasis Cardiomegaly    Consolidation   Edema   Effusion    Emphysema   Fibrosis    Hernia  Infiltration    Mass    Nodule  Pleural_Thickening  Pneumonia   Pneumothorax
0   00000003_000.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Hernia']]  False   0.145712    0.028958    0.205006    0.055228    0.115680    0.376638    0.349124    0.357694    0.122496    0.202218    0.075018    0.118994    0.195345    0.215577
1   00000003_001.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Hernia']]  False   0.132639    0.046136    0.169713    0.092743    0.285383    0.614464    0.311035    0.344040    0.117032    0.447748    0.152327    0.094364    0.174125    0.316022
2   00000003_002.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Hernia']]  False   0.233026    0.042541    0.227911    0.047988    0.116835    0.595102    0.330304    0.367272    0.117985    0.298624    0.109354    0.133473    0.185444    0.379627
3   00000003_003.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1024....   False   0.298693    0.022646    0.237977    0.035348    0.143645    0.487804    0.384509    0.379062    0.083205    0.625744    0.102377    0.207353    0.184517    0.354402
4   00000003_004.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Hernia']]  False   0.522152    0.052897    0.237475    0.082139    0.200029    0.473421    0.377468    0.336104    0.106339    0.488078    0.088047    0.146686    0.200919    0.313684
```

We can use `idxmax` to get the column name of the max value on each row like so :

```py
>>> df["predicted_class"] = df.drop(['file', 'set', 'label', 'bbx'], axis=1).idxmax(axis=1)
>>> df["predicted_class"].head()
0      Emphysema
1      Emphysema
2      Emphysema
3           Mass
4    Atelectasis
Name: predicted_class, dtype: object
```

Then we check if this column name appears in the `labels` column using a `lambda` to get a boolean `True Positive` or `True Negative` value :

```py
>>> df['evaluation'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["predicted_class"] in x["label"], axis=1)
>>> df['evaluation'].head()
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: evaluation, dtype: bool
```

To finish, we can have the `TPR`  for each `class` doing :

```py
>>> df.groupby('predicted_class')['evaluation'].mean()
predicted_class
Atelectasis    0.000000
Emphysema      0.285714
Mass           0.000000
Name: evaluation, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, @tlentali for the detailed answer. I am applying the provided solution on my data frame but there is a problem with finding `df["best_score"] = df.drop('labels', axis=1).idxmax(axis=1)` . It returns me `nan` values of for all row of my data frame.
As you create the data frame and I just copy and paste your code it works fine.  

My question is that is you applied on shared `CSV` or just create the data frame. I dropped the irrelevant columns and prepared my `CSV` as you prepared the data frame.
Please clear this.
Thanks a lot for your concerns.

Comment: I didn't use your data as I built my own from scratch, but I just download yours and I indeed saw why it doesn't work on your side. We have to drop `['file', 'set', 'label', 'bbx']` instead of just `label` and I mispelled `label` with an `s`. I updated the answer, now it works on your data.

Comment: yes you are right I change and drop those `col` but okay let me check once again.
Thank you brother

Comment: Happy to help my friend ! Does it solve you issue ?

Comment: sorry if I am commenting odd:
My supervisor says: 
"To get the single class result to compare each class separately. For each class, you will have 2 arrays (`true_values` and `predictions`) and with that, you can calculate the AUC"
It means if we calculate TPR for a single class during my model predicting that probablites like the supervisor said don't get complex. What is your opinion should I go with that?

Comment: The last part of the answer gives you the `TPR` for each class. You didn't mention the `AUC` in your question, but you can indeed compute it with all the data you got. I agree with your supervisor.

Comment: By dropping all col except single diseaseapplying same thing by adding little addition as you have shown.
Here is what I did base on my supervisor call:

`df = pd.read_csv('/home/ali/Desktop/CX/RpSalWeaklyDet/merge.csv')`

`df = df.drop(['file', 'set', 'bbx', '13 col except single'], axis=1)`

`dff = df.drop(['label'], axis =1)`

`dff["best_score"] = dff.idxmax(axis=1)`

`df['best_score'] = dff['best_score'].values`

`df['evaluation'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["best_score"] in x["label"], axis=1)`

Comment: all struggle in going into the dustbin, supervisor reject the method which I show you above.
Now the new story is that which was the same as you have shown in code but I will find max values for those which contain the label and if there are multi labels then find their max values too that these are `True Positive`.
Now the code is the same as you provided but It's for a single label not for a multi-label to show that the 2nd label has the highest prediction values as in the uploaded file you can see.
please suggest me solution, my mind is not working on it now as no experience in pandas.

Comment: Ok, as it is a new problem, can you make a new question @EngrAli ? Like last time, you can link it here so I will check that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665581/how-to-find-true-postive-only-for-data-frame-while-having-ground-truth
Here is the link
thanks dear
Can I follow on Github? I can't find ur Github

Comment: The new answer is ready my friend, hope it helps you ! Here is my [github account](https://github.com/tlentali). Cheers !