# How to find True Postive only for Data Frame while having Ground Truth?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, model, prediction

first of all, sorry for the long description but I want that everyone understands my problem with what I doing.

I am working on a detection model which predicts 14 different pathologies and I have made an inference file that does prediction for any new test images.
The dataset having test images of about 25k+ and I already find their prediction and made a file like this [Dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19rIxxwd0UF7ageI8SKsZ5WdsIHq_ct5B/view?usp=sharing).

In this data frame I have(little info to understand my scnario):

```
image_name______00000003_000.png
label_____[[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0], [119.195767195767, 339.166137566138, 470.281481481481, 511.458201058202]], ['Cardiomegaly', 'Edema', 'Infiltration']]
Bounding_Box_____True/False
Atelectasis _____0.172639399766922
Cardiomegaly _____0.064461663365364
Consolidation _____0.436323910951614
Edema _____0.152604594826698
Effusion _____0.077432356774807
Emphysema _____0.569778263568878
Fibrosis _____0.333310723304749
Hernia _____0.219542726874351
Infiltration _____0.240452200174332
Mass _____0.291741400957108
Nodule _____0.076222963631153
Pleural_Thickening_____ 0.294208467006683
Pneumonia _____0.281939893960953
Pneumothorax _____0.386653006076813
```

**What I want:**
We can find it by two methods: e.g. getting those rows for each separate class.
Like firstly find all rows which contain `Cardiomegaly` single or multi-label.

Then Apply the below operation below**OR** find as you want and expertise to find the `TP`.

I want if the image which has ground truth like `['Cardiomegaly', 'Edema', 'Infiltration']` and having 14 pathologies probabilities. I want to find `True Positive` if these actual labels having the highest probabilities value for:

Like for `Cardiomegaly` if it found the highest prob- then make a new `col` and put it `True`. I don't know what should I do for multi-label that after finding first what should I do for the 2nd `label` and if its probability is highest then how I can manipulate.
I have done the last attempt with the help of @tlentali Thanks man for helping me out.
Here what I have done:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/ali/Desktop/CX/sample.csv')
df["best_score"] = df.drop(['file', 'set', 'label', 'bbx'], axis=1).idxmax(axis=1)
df['evaluation'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["best_score"] in x["label"], axis=1)
df.groupby('best_score')['evaluation'].mean()
```

which gives me like:

```
best_score
Atelectasis           0.452465
Cardiomegaly          0.250000
Consolidation         0.123164
Edema                 0.029520
Effusion              0.555459
Emphysema             0.068618
Fibrosis              0.066116
Hernia                0.032258
Infiltration          0.400000
Mass                  0.177524
Nodule                0.604167
Pleural_Thickening    0.188482
Pneumonia             0.049133
Pneumothorax          0.108156
Name: evaluation, dtype: float64
```

it's not what I want and it's only for a single label not for multi.
Please help me out and sorry for the long description but it's only that everyone understands what I want.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df
                file    set     label                                        bbx    Atelectasis Cardiomegaly    Consolidation   Edema   Effusion    Emphysema   Fibrosis    Hernia  Infiltration    Mass    Nodule  Pleural_Thickening  Pneumonia   Pneumothorax
0   00000003_000.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Hernia']]  False   0.145712    0.028958    0.205006    0.055228    0.115680    0.376638    0.349124    0.357694    0.122496    0.202218    0.075018    0.118994    0.195345    0.215577
1   00000003_001.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Hernia']]  False   0.132639    0.046136    0.169713    0.092743    0.285383    0.614464    0.311035    0.344040    0.117032    0.447748    0.152327    0.094364    0.174125    0.316022
2   00000003_002.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Hernia']]  False   0.233026    0.042541    0.227911    0.047988    0.116835    0.595102    0.330304    0.367272    0.117985    0.298624    0.109354    0.133473    0.185444    0.379627
3   00000003_003.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1024....   False   0.298693    0.022646    0.237977    0.035348    0.143645    0.487804    0.384509    0.379062    0.083205    0.625744    0.102377    0.207353    0.184517    0.354402
4   00000003_004.png    Test    [[[0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 1024.0]], ['Hernia']]  False   0.522152    0.052897    0.237475    0.082139    0.200029    0.473421    0.377468    0.336104    0.106339    0.488078    0.088047    0.146686    0.200919    0.313684
```

First, we `eval` the column `label` in order to extract the class we expect to predict :

```py
>>> df['label'] = df['label'].apply(eval)
>>> df['class'] = df.label.apply(lambda x: x[1])
>>> df
0                                              [Hernia]
1                                              [Hernia]
2                                              [Hernia]
3                                [Hernia, Infiltration]
4                                              [Hernia]
5                                              [Hernia]
6                                              [Hernia]
7                                              [Hernia]
8                                          [No Finding]
9                             [Emphysema, Pneumothorax]
10                            [Emphysema, Pneumothorax]
11                                 [Pleural_Thickening]
12    [Effusion, Emphysema, Infiltration, Pneumothorax]
13    [Emphysema, Infiltration, Pleural_Thickening, ...
14                             [Effusion, Infiltration]
15                                       [Infiltration]
Name: class, dtype: object
```

Then, we `explode` the column `class` to get an expected class by row like so :

```py
>>> df = df.explode('class')
>>> df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df['class']
0                 Hernia
1                 Hernia
2                 Hernia
3                 Hernia
4           Infiltration
5                 Hernia
6                 Hernia
7                 Hernia
8                 Hernia
9             No Finding
10             Emphysema
11          Pneumothorax
12             Emphysema
13          Pneumothorax
14    Pleural_Thickening
15              Effusion
16             Emphysema
17          Infiltration
18          Pneumothorax
19             Emphysema
20          Infiltration
21    Pleural_Thickening
22          Pneumothorax
23              Effusion
24          Infiltration
25          Infiltration
Name: class, dtype: object
```

Then, we transform the data in dummies format :

```py
>>> classes = ['Atelectasis', 
...            'Cardiomegaly',
...            'Consolidation', 
...            'Edema', 
...            'Effusion', 
...            'Emphysema', 
...            'Fibrosis', 
...            'Hernia',
...            'Infiltration', 
...            'Mass', 
...            'Nodule', 
...            'Pleural_Thickening', 
...            'Pneumonia',
...            'Pneumothorax',
...            'No Finding']
>>> s = df['class']
>>> df_classes = pd.get_dummies(s.apply(pd.Series).stack()).sum(level=0)
>>> df_classes.head()
    Effusion    Emphysema   Hernia  Infiltration    No Finding  Pleural_Thickening  Pneumothorax
0   0           0           1       0               0           0                   0
1   0           0           1       0               0           0                   0
2   0           0           1       0               0           0                   0
3   0           0           1       0               0           0                   0
4   0           0           0       1               0           0                   0
```

As we are currently working on a toy dataset, we have to make some adjustement in order to exploit all the desired classes as dummies format :

```py
>>> df_classes['Atelectasis'] = 0 
>>> df_classes['Cardiomegaly'] = 0 
>>> df_classes['Consolidation'] = 0 
>>> df_classes['Edema'] = 0 
>>> df_classes['Fibrosis'] = 0 
>>> df_classes['Mass'] = 0 
>>> df_classes['Nodule'] = 0 
>>> df_classes['Pneumonia'] = 0 
>>> df['No Finding'] = 0
```

Now, we can use `sklearn` to get our `TRP` and eventually the `AUC` :

```py
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc


n_classes = len(classes)
y_test = df_classes[classes].to_numpy()
y_score = df[classes].to_numpy()

# Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
fpr = dict()
tpr = dict()
roc_auc = dict()
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
# Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])
```

Now, we can have a look at the `roc_auc` values, the `nan` are due to the fact that not all classes are predicted in the toy dataset :

```py
>>> roc_auc
 1: nan,
 2: nan,
 3: nan,
 4: 0.3125,
 5: 0.7613636363636364,
 6: nan,
 7: 0.9479166666666666,
 8: 0.6190476190476191,
 9: nan,
 10: nan,
 11: 0.30208333333333337,
 12: nan,
 13: 0.7840909090909091,
 14: 0.5,
 'micro': 0.66562764158918}
```

We can now plot the `ROC_AUC` curve based on `TPR` and `FPR` for each class (noted `classe` here, some class are empty as we work on a toy dataset) :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure()
lw = 2
classe = 7
plt.plot(fpr[classe], tpr[classe], color='darkorange',
         lw=lw, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc[classe])
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=lw, linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it validate the question ?

Comment: hello senior, I am sorry for the late reply as weekend;
the answer is very satisfactory and I want that explode the columns to find the single highest class probability finding.
I satisfied the supervisor with your different method and my method too. He is okay with all but the last code where you transform the data and then find TPR and FPR is confusing me. 
I have a question: 
Did you transform it for multilabel classification?
if yes then why you are using toy dataset code?
why we are exploiting the data and put zero?
Last one by just copying your code the ROC has no finding `nan`

Comment: after exploiting I again apply your last answer method which works properly.
now I generate new questions which will be easy for me but as a contributor its necessary to share more knowlege.
Thank you tlentali

Comment: Have a look here its my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68707555/how-to-split-multiple-lists-in-a-column-and-make-new-dataframe-and-map-for-speci

Comment: But this answer doesn't validate your previous question ?

Comment: The problem in my last question was a mistake by my supervisor but it helps me a lot and I am glad for your help and I appreciated ur effort very much.
Please upvote my question to improve my reputation thanks